# CDH 5.5.2 OS requirements

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2, centos7, cloudera-cdh

I am going to install CDH 5.5.2 on my CentOS 7.0.1406, will it support. Is my OS compatible with CDH 5.5.2..?

According to requirement documents it will support CentOS 7.1

http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/cm_ig_cm_requirements.html

Answer (score 0):

It will support. As cloudera do not develop CentOS. They put CDH new release on the newest available CentOS. I did many time updated my CDH on the same CentOS but did not face any problem.